# Javascript, how can i make tick boxes required when an answer is placed in a text box

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
<tr>
<td><b>If the registration is for either a Consultant or End User Business</b></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>     <td>Please tick box (multiple choice) their area of business</td></tr Question being asked
<td align="right"><b>Consultant or End User: </b>
<td><font color="red">*</font></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="Data" value="Yes">Data Centres
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Power" value="Yes">Power Plants
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Mining" value="Yes">Mining
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Telecom" value="Yes">Telecom
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Governmental" value="Yes">Governmental
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Airports" value="Yes">Airports
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Hotel" value="Yes">Hotel/Residential
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" value="Yes">Healthcare 
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Shopping" value="Yes">Shopping Complex
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Industries" value="Yes">Industries / Manufacturing
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Transport" value="Yes">Transport
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Utilities" value="Yes">Utilities
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Water" value="Yes">Water Treatment
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Construction" value="Yes">Construction
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Other" value="Yes">Other
  <br />

</td>   </tr>   <tr> <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#dadada"> </tr>
<tr>
```

checkboxes to be ticked if answer provided

UPDATE : Here is the code for textfield

```
    <tr> 
      <td align="right"><strong>Consulting Company Name: </strong><font color="red">*</font></td> 
      <td><input size="30" name="ConCompany" class="required"/></td> 
   </tr>
```

Comment: Where is the textbox?

Comment: Apologies, this is the text box:      <tr>
    <td align="right"><strong>Consulting Company Name: </strong>
    <td><font color="red">*</font></td>
    <td><input size="30" name="ConCompany"  class="required"/></td>
  </tr>

Comment: Edit it in your question...also it doesnt look good without submit button...

Comment: Make clear your Question and you made lots of html tag missing

Comment: This is my complete code:

Answer (score 0):

use a `button` with some `id` like `submitbtn` button like

```
<input type="button" id="submitbtn" value="Submit" />
```

Add `id` to your `textbox` like `id=ConCompany`

dd `id`s to your checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Data" id="10" value="Yes">Data Centres
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Power" id="11" value="Yes">Power Plants
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Mining" id="12" value="Yes">Mining
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Telecom" id="13" value="Yes">Telecom
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Governmental"  id="14" value="Yes">Governmental
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Airports" id="15" value="Yes">Airports
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Hotel" id="16" value="Yes">Hotel/Residential
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Healthcare" id="17" value="Yes">Healthcare 
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Shopping"  id="18" value="Yes">Shopping Complex
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Industries" id="19" value="Yes">Industries / Manufacturing
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Transport" id="20" value="Yes">Transport
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Utilities" id="21" value="Yes">Utilities
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Water"  id="22" value="Yes">Water Treatment
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Construction"  id="23" value="Yes">Construction
```

Now use the following javascript :

```
document.getElementById('submitbtn').onclick = function () {
    if(document.getElementById('ConCompany').value != "")
     {
       var count = 0;
        for ( var i = 10 ; i <= 23 ; i++)
          {
             if(document.getElementById(i).value == "Yes")
                count++;
          }
       if(count == 0)
       {
         alert("Please select the area of business ");
          return;
       }
      }
      document.FormName.submit();
 }
```

Comment: Should the submitbtn button be a radio button to denote that they completed the text box?
Or do i simply place the javascript at the top of my form and change the html as noted?

Comment: the `submit` button should be a normal button like `<input type="button" id="submitbtn" value="Submit" />`

Answer (score 0):

in first step I would add an id to your textfield, that you can add an eventhandler via JavaScript.

```
  <td><input id="company" size="30" name="ConCompany" class="required"/></td>
```

Add Eventhandler:

```
document.getElementById('company').addEventListener('change', setCheckboxesRequired);
```

Create function to set all checkboxes required:

```
function setCheckboxesRequired() {
  var allInputs, allCheckboxes, textValue, bSetRequired, tmpInput, tmpCheckbox;

  // Retrieve all input elements
  allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  allCheckboxes = [];

  // put all inputs with type = checkbox in allCheckboxes variable
  for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    tmpInput = allInputs[i];

    if (tmpInput.type === 'checkbox') {
      allCheckboxes.push(tmpInput);
    }
  }

  // determine if class should be set
  textValue = document.getElementById('company').value;
  if (textValue === null || textValue === "") {
    bSetRequired = false;
  } else {
    bSetRequired = true;
  }

  // iteration through all checkboxes
  for (var j = 0; j < allCheckboxes.length; j++) {
    tmpCheckbox = allCheckboxes[j];

    // set or delete class
    if (bSetRequired) {
      tmpCheckbox.className = tmpCheckbox.className + ' required';
    } else {
      tmpCheckbox.className = tmpCheckbox.className.replace('required', '');
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you want to set HTML5 [required-attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) instead of your 'required'-class change the last for-loop to the following:

```
  for (var j = 0; j < allCheckboxes.length; j++) {
    tmpCheckbox = allCheckboxes[j];
    tmpCheckbox.required = bSetRequired;
  }
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Can you explain were the event handler goes in relation to the question, the check boxes and the javascript

Comment: the eventhandler ensures, that the function 'setCheckboxesRequired' will run whenever the value of the textfield changes. In this function I retrieve all input elements, where I eleminate all elements with type != checkbox. Then I check if the textfield has a value (textfield got new text) or no value (text were deleted). And after that I added the 'required' class or set 'required' attribute. If you dont understand my code I recommend to read a tutorial of using JavaScript.